# Zero moment of arc length measure

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Suppose $\gamma$ is a simple smooth closed curve and is not a circle. Does there exist a monomial $z^n$ so that $\int_{\gamma}z^n ds(z)=0$ for some positive integer $n$?
(In here, $ds$ is the arc length measure.)

Comment: Why do you insists for it not to be a circle? Shouldn't it be zero for all $n$ from the residue theorem?

Comment: Obviously if its the unit disk its true for all $n=1,2,\cdots$.It seems to me that circle is the only smooth curve with with monomial zero moments.

Comment: Why? It is preserved via homotopy, i.e. for any "simple smooth closed curve".

Comment: No. Its easy to find an ellipse, $E,$ with non-zero $\int_E z^n ds(z).$

Comment: Wait, the fact that you are integrating in $\mathrm{d}s$ and not in  $\mathrm{d}z$ may change something... But maybe it's just notation. Mind showing me your example?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem

Comment: $z^n ds=z^n f(z) dz$ and is no necessarily analytic.in fact might not be analytic at any point inside our domain.

Comment: If $\mathrm{d}s$ is the arc length measure then shouldn't it depend on the path $\gamma$ on which we are integrating? Then shouldn't even $z$ be calculated on something? But putting all this useless notation aside: mind showing me your example of ellipse on which the integral is not zero?

Comment: If you are interested in an answer mind showing what your vision is? I am really curious about your example!